# Shell script not executing a python file

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to run a script which in turn should execute a basic python script.
This is the shell script:

```
#!usr/bin/bash
mv ~/Desktop/source/movable.py ~/Desktop/dest
cd ~/Desktop/dest
pwd
ls -lah
chmod +x movable.py
python movable.py
echo "Just ran a python file from a shell script"
```

This is the python script:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import os
print("movable transfered to dest")
os.system("pwd")
os.system("mv ~/Desktop/dest/movable.py ~/Desktop/source")
print("movable transfered to dest")
os.system("cd ~/Desktop/source")
os.system("pwd")
```

Q1. The shell script is not executing the python file. What am I doing wrong?
Q2. Do I need to write the first line `#!usr/bin/python` in the python script?
Thank you.

Comment: The first line is not needed but only recommended, and in that you should actually be careful.

Comment: The +x thing is also not needed considering the way you call the script (I think)

Comment: Also beware: The `cd` command you write in there will have no effect (in the Python script)

Comment: Then, how can we change directories?

Comment: Python probably has some chdir function, perhaps in `io`? Not sure (I don't have a lot of experience with Python in particular, and it seems you don't either, as you really do a Bash script with a few Python additions)

Comment: change directory `os.chdir(directory_name)`, display current direcotry `os.getcwd()` (instead of `os.system('pwd')`)

Comment: BTW: you can use `os.rename(old_name, new_name)` to move file to new place. But `new_name` can't be only directory - it has to be path with filename. PS. try `shutil.move(old_name, new_directory)`

Comment: Please provide the actual output from running the script

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a '/' in the shebang line:

```
#!usr/bin/python
```

should be

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Another thing I noticed was, you are calling cd in os.system.  Since that command would be executed in a sub shell, it won't change the current directory of the calling script process.

Comment: It's working by itself, apparently the missing slash is not really missed :p. I see that the current dir is not changed. How can I do that? Also, I was trying this from python file : `os.system("pid=$$")`
`os.system("echo 'This is pid=$pid'")` But it does not work. Can you tell me how can I execute two related statements like the ones above.